# Jmeter run single thread group sequentially in repetitive manner

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

How can we run single Thread Group sequentially. I have one thread group with several requests. Consider following scenario :

```
No. of Threads : 30
Ramp Up period: 60
Loop Count: 1
```

This means Jmeter will request 30 no of users in 60 secs. I need to run this scenario in repetitive manner but sequentially. That means once the first set of requests completed, new set of requests should run and goes on.

How can we configure Thread groups to run like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Set No. of Threads to 1 and Loop Count to however many iterations you desire.

Comment: Loop Count makes that number of parallel requests. It does not work as iteration of whole Thread group. So if we set Loop Count to 4, it wont execute whole Thread group 4 times repetitively, instead it will do 4 parallel request at a same time instead of 1.

Comment: If we set No. of Threads to 1, that means only one Thread(User) will hit the system at one point of time. What if we want to generate a scenario where, i.e., 100 users hits system in 60 seconds, and again after that lot is completed, again next 100 users comes in next 60 seconds. and so on. So for every 60 seconds, 100 users come to the system. How to generate that scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

I think BlazeMeter's **Concurrency Thread Group** will solve the problem.

For example-

Total threads = 300

ramp-up time = 3 mins

Ramp-up step count = 3

The result will be for every 60 seconds 100 users will hit the system.

[image: screen shot]

For Blazemeter's Concurrency Thread Group [Refer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function)

Hope this helps.